# What is the gtkmm equivalent to g_signal_handlers_block_by_func()?

Tags: c++, c, gtkmm

I need to block signals that I emit (indirectly) myself.

In C one could use g_signal_handlers_block_by_func() and the sister function unblock.

What can I use in C++ gtkmm?

I have a gtkmm dlna player, that emits the **changed** signal to a Gtk::HScale Widet each second, because it gets (from the outside) a signal that the song that just plays. And then I seek to the position that just where current, which set the song back a split second...

I would like to block my on changes from the seek, because I saw that a C program did that with g_signal_handlers_block_by_func.

Comment: found it myself: the return value for the connect call has a block/unblock method.

Comment: You can post it as an answer to answer your own question!

Answer (score 4):

since ptomato asked:

I never realized, that the connect method has a valuable return value:

so if you connect the signals like this:

```
mywidget_connection = mywidget.signal_value_changed().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyClass::on_value_changed ));
```

In my situation I have 2 ways to change the value: 
1.) someone pulls a slider: should update the value and seek
2.) the timer comes along and tells the new position: should update the value but not seek.

then you can block/unblock like this:

```
mywidget_connection.block();
mywidget.set_value(new_value);
mywidget_connection.unblock();
```

and this does not emit the changed signal.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need! Thanks a lot for the clear explanation of both your situation and the solution.

Comment: ...however, now that I look at this again, it would've been worth mentioning that the type of the returned object is [`sigc::connection`](http://libsigc.sourceforge.net/libsigc2/docs/reference/html/structsigc_1_1connection.html), from [libsigc++](http://libsigc.sourceforge.net/), a C++ callback library used heavily by the *`mm` libraries.

Comment: Ho do I give you more points? Why is this not documented anywhere?